# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 On Raspberry Pi 4 Can't SSH "Access denied"

Tags: 18.04, ssh, raspberrypi

after using the pi imager and writing to my microSD card, I am blocked from installing Ubuntu Server and Desktop on my 64 bit Raspberry Pi.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview

I am following this tutorial, where it says nothing about having an Ubuntu One account.  After following all instructions, I get a screen the prompts me to login via ssh *ubuntuUsername*@*local_IP_address*

On my laptop, I'm using Putty and my local_IP_address for sshing into my Pi.  When prompted for a login, I enter my ubuntuUsername then UbuntuOne password.  No passwords are working, I keep getting an "Access denied" message.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: If you are prompted for a username/password, it's 'ubuntu' and 'ubuntu'. If you were using the SSH keys on file with Ubuntu One, then you would be prompted for neither (username would be in the ssh connection string, no password because there is an ssh key). Did you remember to reboot the second time if using WiFi? Are you *absolutely sure* you are using the correct IP address? Are you *absolutely sure* that you installed Ubuntu Server instead of Ubuntu Core or something else?